# Why doesn't DRF's serializer validate PositiveSmallIntegerField?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

Using Django 1.11 and Django Rest Framework 3.7, I have a Person model

```
class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

with a PersonSerializer

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'age', 'email')
```

and a ListCreate view

```
class PersonList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

Using HTTPie, I can create a Person like this:

```
$ http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/people/ name=Alice age=26 email=alice@example.com
HTTP/1.0 201 Created
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 60
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 10 Dec 2017 15:00:28 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.11
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "age": 26,
    "email": "alice@example.com",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Alice"
}
```

When I create a Person with a bad email address, I get an error:

```
$ http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/people/ name=Bob age=33 email=oops
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 42
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 10 Dec 2017 15:01:08 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.11
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "email": [
        "Enter a valid email address."
    ]
}
```

DRF knows it's an EmailField and automatically applies validation, so far so good.

However, when I create a Person with a bad age (negative number), I get no error:

```
$ http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/people/ name=Charlie age=-10 email=charlie@example
.com
HTTP/1.0 201 Created
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 65
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 10 Dec 2017 15:03:25 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.11
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "age": -10,
    "email": "charlie@example.com",
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Charlie"
}
```

Now my database has been polluted with bad data.  I have no problem doing the work to validate my inputs, but

- DRF correctly validated the email field, leading me to believe it will validate inputs based on the type of field in the model.
- If I had POSTed from an html form, Django's ModelForm would and does validate both the email and age fields.
- If I had created a Person from the standard Django Admin, it also would and does validate both the email and age fields.

Based on those facts, my questions are:

(A) Why does DRF's serializer validate EmailField, but not PositiveSmallIntegerField?

(B) Where am I supposed to validate the 'age' field to make sure it's positive?  Model? Serializer? View?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @StephenRauch SQLite with the built-in dev server.

Comment: @epalm One possibility, but can't test right now so comment rather than answer: Maybe DRF is not using the default 0..maxint that forms/admin are using but EmailField doesn't need any parameters defined so it works. If that's true, try adding parameters (good idea anyway) in the Model - e.g., min_value=0, max_value=120 and see if that carries through to DRF.

Comment: @manassehkatz Looking at the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#integerfield, neither IntegerField nor PositiveSmallIntegerField (nor any other field for that matter) have a min_value option.

Comment: @epalm - You're right! I keep forgetting (until I need to do it myself) that Django, for some reason I don't quite understand, doesn't provide min & max as part of integer fields. Posting an answer shortly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add validators to the field in the Model:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(120)])
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this better than Serializer validation (eg what if I apply the correct validation rules to one Serializer, but "forget" to apply it to another?).  Having the validation in the model has me covered either way.  Can we agree though that adding MinValueValidator(0) to a field called PositiveIntegerField or PositiveSmallIntegerField is ridiculous?

Comment: Agreed! That appears to be a bug (missing feature...) in DRF. But for Age, unlike some possible fields, there really is a Max so putting in Min & Max isn't a big deal. But of course you could do the same thing with an ordinary SmallIntegerField. My suspicion is that the reason integer fields don't have native Min & Max functions is that they don't translate into database-specific code. But I have found other instances where MySQL could support ORM functions directly and Django doesn't use those features of MySQL, so there is no real pattern that I can see.

Answer (score 5):

In DRF, IntegerField corresponds to PositiveIntegerField so you can set max and min value limitation on it.

eg:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    age = serializers.IntegerField(max_value=100, min_value=1)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'age', 'email')
```

Comment: This answers Question B, thank you for that. But I'm still unsatisfied because, I don't know when DRF validates based on the Model, and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If one need to perform more operation with integer fields in models

```
class YOURSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

age= serializers.IntegerField(required=True)


    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
      age= data.get('age', None)
    
      if age == 18:
          raise serializers.ValidationError("Age 18 people are given special discount, Congrats!")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.